# How do I convert an expression to a string while keeping -> as one symbol?

Tags: string-manipulation

When I write `ToString[a->b]`, regardless of whether the input uses the right-arrow symbol or `-` and `>` separately, it comes out as `"a -> b"` with `-` and `>`. If I just write `"->"` but with the right-arrow symbol, that's what I get in the output, so it's possible to get the arrow to show up in a string, but is there a good way to do this without having to break up the expression before using `ToString`?

Comment: does `ToString[a -> b, StandardForm]` give what you want?

Comment: @kglr Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StandardForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html) in the second argument of `ToString`:

```
ToString[a -> b, StandardForm]
```

[image]